# Dropbox is not syncing anymore after upgrade to Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, sync, dropbox

I upgraded from Kubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. Now the Dropbox icon keeps switching between "network folder" and "box with circular arrows" as if a lot were going up and down, but actually nothing is coming down or going up (I'm comparing with the files on the web interface and my phone with Dropbox).

Advanced reinstall of Dropbox (with deleting configuration files) https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/advanced-reinstall has not helped. Installing the deb file from the Dropbox website instead of from the Ubuntu repository has not helped, either.

Stopping Dropbox, deleting/moving all local files, then waiting 20 hours to download all files again worked once - now I'm back at the previous stage, edits/new files don't go up, new photos that have uploaded from my phone to the cloud are not coming down, the icon keeps blinking.

Edit:

In /var/log/syslog.1 I found three entries like these:

"Jun 25 22:06:47 lilly Â»[34300]: Unable to monitor entire Dropbox folder hierarchy. Please run "echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p" and restart Dropbox to fix the problem."

(with differing special characters before 34300).

I've tried the command and restarted Dropbox. For a few second I thought the situation had improved, because now the submenu "recently changed files" showed some files. But now everything is as before.

By the way the submenu "snooze notifications" doesn't load most of the time (it should show 30 minutes, 1 hour and until tomorrow). That was already so before I used the command.

dropbox filestatus * shows "unwatched" for all files (both before and after trying the above command). I have not unselected any subfolders from synchronization in the settings.

Second edit:
~/.dropbox-dist$ strace ./dropboxd

yields a lot of output like this mentioning "The resource is currently not available":

futex(0x7f5c79e00e94, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=5279, tv_nsec=506637588}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY)
= -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
futex(0x7f5c79e00ee8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x7f5c79e00e98, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
recvmsg(24, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=23, events=POLLIN}, {fd=24,
events=POLLIN}], 5, 499) = 1 ([{fd=14, revents=POLLIN}])
read(14, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)        = 8
write(29, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)        = 8
futex(0x7f5bb000dd70, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
recvmsg(24, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)         = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=23, events=POLLIN}, {fd=24,
events=POLLIN}], 5, 487) = 0 (Timeout)
futex(0x7f5c79e00e90, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x7f5c79e00e98, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(29, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)        = 8

I'm not sure if this is meaningful or indicates a problem.

Any ideas what to try?

Answer (score 1):

It's working again.
I ran ~/.dropbox-dist$ strace -f ./dropboxd.
It often showed ("Vorgang nicht zulässig" = "activity not allowed"):
[pid 8640] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/monika/Data/Dropbox/Dateien/programme/Videobearbeitung/software/otr-verwaltung3p/data/tools/intern-VirtualDub/wine/dosdevices/z:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/legal/java.compiler", O_RDONLY|O_NOATIME|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 EPERM (Vorgang nicht zulässig) zu sehen
I moved the entire folder Videobearbeitung out of the Dropbox folder be on the safe side and restarted Dropbox.
Immediately things improved, a notification showed "90 files deleted from Dropbox", my husband's PC showed "9 files changed" for a shared folder and after a while the systray icon stopped blinking and just showed the box (without arrows).

(The weird thing is that I had deleted all local files at one point and Dropbox had downloaded them - including the offending one.)

The "echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p" probably also was part of the solution.